# How can i use Files Connect to upload an attachment with apex, to Google Drive?

Tags: apex, attachment, upload, google-drive

I'm new to this salesforce world and i recently discovered i can synchronize my salesforce instance with a Google Drive. I already have a connection established using Files Connect to my Google Drive, and now i need to upload attachments to my drive for the user to download later from a folder with all of the attachments that he/she needs using apex. How can i do this? Do i have to use Chatter REST Api? And if yes how? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

File connect let you use google drive as local drive for attachments only.

To upload files from salesforce to google drives, you have to use Rest API.